# Load balancing via Eureka, ribbon?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-ribbon

1. Does Eureka provide load balancing out of the box, is there a need for another
   dependency?
2. Why Ribbon instead of Eureka?
3. Why use load balancing via an API gateway?
4. spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer, why is this required?
5. Client side balancing or server side load balancing, why use one over the other?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. No it does not, Eureka is a service registry and service discovery tool
2. "With", not "instead of": Eureka holds the list of services, Ribbon downloads them and does load balancing on the client side
3. I'm not 100% sure I understand this, does this article help: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/microservices-client-side-load-balancing-amit-kumar-sharma
4. Not required but if you want client side loadbalancing, it is a simple starting point, see the guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-cloud-loadbalancer/
5. See answer #3

Comment: also, spring cloud load balancer is like a replacement for ribbon

Comment: Yes, it is. Spring Cloud Netflix support for Ribbon is no longer there. We do not suggest using it in projects anymore.